# CMake - Copy file only if it doesnt exist

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I would like to copy files at postbuild with cmake to the build directory, but only if they dont exist yet.

I know that there is a "copy_if_different" switch for "add_custom_command", but I cant find something like "copy_if_doesnt_exist".

Currently I am stuck with this:

```
file(GLOB CONFIGURATION_DATA ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/configurations/*)

foreach(data ${CONFIGURATION_DATA})
    #only copy if file doesnt exists
    if(NOT EXISTS ?? how to get same path as - $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME_STR}>/data/configurations) )
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME_STR} POST_BUILD 
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy 
        ${data}
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME_STR}>/data/configurations)
    endif()
endforeach()
```

where I don't know how to get the destination file path

```
$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME_STR}>/data/configurations
```

in order to put it to if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the not directly supported cases the [`file(GENERATE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command is very useful (since it does evaluate [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)).

So in your case I've successfully tested the following code example:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

if (POLICY CMP0070)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0070 NEW)
endif()

project(CopyFileIfNotExists)

file(
    GENERATE 
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CopyConfigurationData$<CONFIG>.cmake"
        CONTENT 
            "if (NOT EXISTS \"$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/data/configurations\")
                execute_process(
                     COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E copy_directory
                         \"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/configurations\"
                         \"$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/data/configurations\"
                )
            endif()"
)

file(WRITE "main.cpp" "int main() { return 0; }")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} 
    POST_BUILD 
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "CopyConfigurationData$<CONFIG>.cmake"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

**Alternative**

Or if it's ok to run with every CMake (re-)configuration just add the following instead of a post-build step:

```perl
file(
    GLOB 
        CONFIGURATION_DATA 
        RELATIVE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/configurations/*"
 )

foreach(data IN LISTS CONFIGURATION_DATA)
    file(
        GENERATE 
            OUTPUT "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/${data}"
            INPUT  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${data}"
    )
endforeach()
```

**Alternative: Optimized Version**

Utilizing [`file(COPY ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) the shortest script based version I can think of that also optimizes already existing items out

> "Copying preserves input file timestamps, and optimizes out a file if it exists at the destination with the same timestamp."

looks like this:

```perl
file(
    GENERATE 
        OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CopyConfigurationData$<CONFIG>.cmake"
        CONTENT "file(
                    COPY \"${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/configurations\"
                    DESTINATION \"$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/data\"
                 )"
)
```

Comment: great answer! I have two additional questions, in order to understand the things better. Is it possible to achieve the first option without creating a new cmake file, and is it possible to check the existance of the specific files instead of folders?

Comment: @GpG You're welcome. No, you need to generate script files because "copy if not exists" is not available as a single line shell command. And yes, in the script file you could put any operation you want. Probably it would be best for checking individual files to put the `file(GLOB ...` expression inside your script. And if the script gets more complex I would prefer a `INPUT` source file over the shown inline `CONTENT` approach.

Comment: @GpG Added an alternative with `file(COPY ...)` which would not copy files that are already existing.